# Add class to menu ul with active child

Tags: menus, jquery, navigation

I'm trying to add the class `is-active` to the ul when the ul has an active child. This is because Foundation requires that (i'm using FoundationPress as a base theme) This is the markup i'm after:

```
<ul class="vertical menu" data-multi-open="false" data-accordion-menu>
  <li><a href="/home/">Home</a>
    <ul class="vertical nested menu is-active">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="/sample-page/distribution/">Distribution</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="/sample-page/production/">Production</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to hook in to `nav_menu_css_class` or do i have to make a custom walker or how should i go about to achieve this?

Comment: The larent <li> of an <ul> that has an active child gets multiple classes of which `current-menu-ancestor` is it possible that you just use that instead of is-active? Hooking into nav_menu_css_class by its filter is no use since the <ul> elements don't get classes to begin with. If you need that, then indeed use a custom Walker.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow Foundation/FoundationPress requires it to be on the <ul>. Thanks, that excludes the hook and leaves the custom walker (or modifying foundation/foundationpress) as solution.

Comment: You can just add custom CSS that overrides the FoundationPress one, shouldn't be too much lines of code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly could build a custom walker, but perhaps the easiest way out is jquery:

```
$("li.active").parent().addClass("is-active");
```

Comment: This works great. Just feels wrong :P. I'll mark it as solved as long as there is no one with a backend solution.

A heads up if someone else is having the same issue. Make sure to add the class before Foundation is initiated.

Comment: But the backend solution is to use a custom Walker which is one of the reasons they exist.

jQuery ofcourse is a solution, but people without Javascript turned on simply won't benefit.

Comment: @Jeffrey definitely true. On the other hand, so many sites depend on javascript these days hardly anybody has it turned off anymore.

Comment: @cjbj Google has it turned off ;) You shouldn't rely on Javascript for a regular website but always offer non Javascript alternatives. If you have a Javascript driven web-application that doesn't need SEO ranking, sure :)!